# Linq group by Sum but also return 0 if sum is null

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the following type:

```
class ItemTotals
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the totals for each ItemType using this:

```
        var items = new List<ItemTotals>
        {
            new ItemTotals
            {
                Total = 10,
                ItemType = "X"
            },
            new ItemTotals
            {
                Total = 10,
                ItemType = "X"
            },
            new ItemTotals
            {
                Total = -5,
                ItemType = "Y"
            },
            new ItemTotals
            {
                Total = -20,
                ItemType = "Y"
            }
        };


        List<ItemTotals> query = items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemType)
                                      .Select(x => new ItemTotals
                                      {
                                          ItemType = x.Key,
                                          Total = x.Sum(z => z.Total)
                                      }).ToList();
```

This gives me total for X as 20 and Total Y as -25. But suppose if all of the itemtypes are X then I get only one result with total as -5 for X and no result for Total Y which I want as 0, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: If there is no Y in the list, how does the algorithm no it exists at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines after the list initialization

```
items.Add(new ItemTotals {Total = 0, ItemType = "X"});
items.Add(new ItemTotals {Total = 0, ItemType = "Y"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the types which are not included in the list and add them inside loop:

```
List<string> itemTypes = new List<string>() {"X", "Y", "Z"};

foreach(var type in itemTypes)
{
     if(!items.Any(x => x.ItemType == type)
           items.Add(new ItemTotals() {ItemType = type, Total = 0})
}

List<ItemTotals> query = items.GroupBy(x => x.ItemType)....
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to prepend a collection of known names paired with zeros to the collection, like this:

```
var[] names = new {"X", "Y", "Z"};
List<ItemTotals> query = items
    .Concat(names.Select(n => new ItemTotals {Total = 0, ItemType = n}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ItemType)
    ... // And so on
```

The `Concat` ensures that there is at least one item for each name, and that the total for that item is zero. In a way, the added items serve as "sentinels": if an item name is there, they make no difference, but if the name is not there, they ensure that a line with zero is added to the result.